# How to determine the reaction of a strong electrolyte?

Tags: acid-base, ions

I'm told the $\ce{KMnO4}$ is a strong electrolyte.

How can I figure out how the reaction looks like?

Comment: The reaction of what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{HMnO4}$ is s a strong acid (compare oxidation state with perchloric acid).  Its anion is then a weak base.  The salt is completely dissociated in water solution.